# Is today (April 8, 2020) the first time the NYTimes has had content superimposed on its name?

Tags: united-states, new-york, journalism

I notice that today's print edition of the New York Times has part of it's front page infographic overlaid on the name of the paper. As a frequent reader, this stands out to me because while this kind of thing is common for magazines, I can't recall ever seeing it in the NYTimes.

I'm aware that infographics are probably a relatively recent addition to the paper (although I can't find a date for this). Has the NYTimes ever had any kind of content superimposed on it's name before--article text, a photograph, or part of an infographic?

[image]

Comment: Any other times were quite likely also during this modern era of electronic publishing, as the era of physical presses would not have allowed for this (unless someone was exceptionally clever, which I suppose someone always is). It would be a fun task for someone to figure out how to show its definitely the first.

Comment: Magazines have been doing it since the [sixties at least](https://www.rollingstonesnet.com/images/RS191.jpg), though they have a longer timeline, larger budget.  But I don't recall a newspaper doing it before this.

Comment: "Timesmachine" has papers for 150 years through 2002.  Paywalled: https://timesmachine.nytimes.com/browser